# How to correct visual alignment issues in PHP/CSS code?

Tags: php, html, css, opencart

Although I have a decent amount of desktop/mobile coding experience, I'm a n00b when it comes to web related languages, hence I need some help .. I have this OpenCart installation in which I've applied a theme, which has some visual errors when its displaying Options for a given Product.

Example:

[image]

I would like to do the editing needed to make it like this:

[image]

Or at least like this:

[image]

Now I've identified the PHP template code which is reading the Options data and is populating the UI controls, and I think I've also identified the CSS stylesheet which is applying the theme. I just need to know what change I need to do and where.

The PHP template code I think is relevant is this (Full file here: http://pastebin.com/zG0cXQX2):

```
<?php if ($options) { ?>
      <div class="options">
        <h2><?php echo $text_option; ?></h2>

        <?php foreach ($options as $option) { ?>
        <?php if ($option['type'] == 'select') { ?>
        <div id="option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="option">

          <b><?php echo $option['name']; ?>:</b>
          <?php if ($option['required']) { ?>
          <span class="required">*</span>
          <?php } ?><br />
          <select name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]">
            <option value=""><?php echo $text_select; ?></option>
            <?php foreach ($option['option_value'] as $option_value) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>"><?php echo $option_value['name']; ?>
            <?php if ($option_value['price']) { ?>
            (<?php echo $option_value['price_prefix']; ?><?php echo $option_value['price']; ?>)
            <?php } ?>
            </option>
            <?php } ?>
          </select>
        </div>

        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($option['type'] == 'radio') { ?>
        <div id="option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="option boss_radio">

          <b><?php echo $option['name']; ?>:</b>
           <?php if ($option['required']) { ?>
          <span class="required">*</span>
          <?php } ?>
          <br />
          <?php foreach ($option['option_value'] as $option_value) { ?>
          <input type="radio" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>" id="option-value-<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>" />
          <label for="option-value-<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>"><?php echo $option_value['name']; ?>
            <?php if ($option_value['price']) { ?>
            (<?php echo $option_value['price_prefix']; ?><?php echo $option_value['price']; ?>)
            <?php } ?>
          </label>
          <br />
          <?php } ?>
        </div>

        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($option['type'] == 'checkbox') { ?>
        <div id="option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="option boss_checkbox">

          <b><?php echo $option['name']; ?>:</b>
          <?php if ($option['required']) { ?>
          <span class="required">*</span>
          <?php } ?>
          <br />
          <?php foreach ($option['option_value'] as $option_value) { ?>
          <input type="checkbox" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>][]" value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>" id="option-value-<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>" />
          <label for="option-value-<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>"><?php echo $option_value['name']; ?>
            <?php if ($option_value['price']) { ?>
            (<?php echo $option_value['price_prefix']; ?><?php echo $option_value['price']; ?>)
            <?php } ?>
          </label>
          <br />
          <?php } ?>
        </div>

        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($option['type'] == 'image') { ?>
        <div id="option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="option">

          <b><?php echo $option['name']; ?>:</b>
          <?php if ($option['required']) { ?>
          <span class="required">*</span>
          <?php } ?>
          <br />
          <table class="option-image">
            <?php foreach ($option['option_value'] as $option_value) { ?>
            <tr>
              <td style="width: 1px;"><input type="radio" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>" id="option-value-<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>" /></td>
              <td><label for="option-value-<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $option_value['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $option_value['name'] . ($option_value['price'] ? ' ' . $option_value['price_prefix'] . $option_value['price'] : ''); ?>" /></label></td>
              <td><label for="option-value-<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>"><?php echo $option_value['name']; ?>
                  <?php if ($option_value['price']) { ?>
                  (<?php echo $option_value['price_prefix']; ?><?php echo $option_value['price']; ?>)
                  <?php } ?>
                </label></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
          </table>
        </div>

        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($option['type'] == 'text') { ?>
        <div id="option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="option">

          <b><?php echo $option['name']; ?>:</b>
          <?php if ($option['required']) { ?>
          <span class="required">*</span>
          <?php } ?>
          <br />
          <input type="text" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $option['option_value']; ?>" />
        </div>

        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($option['type'] == 'textarea') { ?>
        <div id="option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="option">

          <b><?php echo $option['name']; ?>:</b>
          <?php if ($option['required']) { ?>
          <span class="required">*</span>
          <?php } ?><br />
          <textarea name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" cols="40" rows="5"><?php echo $option['option_value']; ?></textarea>
        </div>

        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($option['type'] == 'file') { ?>
        <div id="option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="option">

          <b><?php echo $option['name']; ?>:</b>
          <?php if ($option['required']) { ?>
          <span class="required">*</span>
          <?php } ?>
          <br />
          <span class="boss_button button_black">
          <input type="button" value="<?php echo $button_upload; ?>" id="button-option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="button"></span>
          <input type="hidden" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" value="" />
        </div>

        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($option['type'] == 'date') { ?>
        <div id="option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="option">

          <b><?php echo $option['name']; ?>:</b>
          <?php if ($option['required']) { ?>
          <span class="required">*</span>
          <?php } ?>
          <br />
          <input type="text" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $option['option_value']; ?>" class="date" />
        </div>

        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($option['type'] == 'datetime') { ?>
        <div id="option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="option">

          <b><?php echo $option['name']; ?>:</b>
          <?php if ($option['required']) { ?>
          <span class="required">*</span>
          <?php } ?>
          <br />
          <input type="text" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $option['option_value']; ?>" class="datetime" />
        </div>

        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($option['type'] == 'time') { ?>
        <div id="option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="option">

          <b><?php echo $option['name']; ?>:</b>
          <?php if ($option['required']) { ?>
          <span class="required">*</span>
          <?php } ?>
          <br />
          <input type="text" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $option['option_value']; ?>" class="time" />
        </div>
        <br />
        <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
      </div>      
      <?php } ?>
```

The CSS styling I see is this (Full file here: http://pastebin.com/C4ZGiyqB):

```
.product-info .options {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 0 0 22px 0;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    color: #5d5d5d;
}
.product-info .options select { width:246px; margin-top:5px}
.product-info .options input[type="text"] { width:236px;margin-top:5px}
.product-info .options textarea { width:406px;margin-top:5px }
.product-info .options h2 {
    text-transform:uppercase; font-size:11px;margin-bottom:0;
}
.product-info .options b {  
    color:#5d5d5d;
    padding-bottom:5px
}
.product-info .option { margin-top:13px}
.product-info .option  .boss_button.button_black { margin-top:10px; display: inline-block;}
.product-info .option.boss_radio { float:left; width:39%}
.product-info .option.boss_checkbox{ float:left; width:61%} 

.product-info .option-image {
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.product-info .option-image label {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

}
.product-info .option-image img {
    margin-right: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    cursor: pointer;
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction, I'll be very grateful.

**EDIT:**

The exact page on which this formatting issue can be seen is this:

http://blu-rays.pk/opencart_test/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=40

Comment: Instead of the php code, can you post the actual generated HTML? Also if you could reproduce your issue at http://www.jsfiddle.net, helping would be faster.

Comment: Or could You share the link with us? I could inspect the problem and advise the solution (at least I believe so)...

Comment: @Arbel, you can see the generated HTML on the above linked page. Unfortunately I've never used jsfiddle.net for such big issues, so I'm not sure how that helps in this scenario :)

Comment: This is the URL where is problem can be seen: http://blu-rays.pk/opencart_test/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=40

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the "Inspect Element with Firebug" option of Firebug while using Firefox to modify the CSS.  It is a very helpful tool for finding, correcting, and experimenting with CSS.  It is a Firefox plug-in.
https://getfirebug.com/
I know this doesn't give you the exact solution to this problem but hopefully it provides the fishing pole instead of giving you the fish.
Maybe someone else out there has some time to give you the fish too.

I took a look at your sample page and saw the border going through the text label that reads "Radio".  To correct that problem I modified the following CSS to remove the float:

```
.product-info .option.boss_radio {
    float: left;
    width: 39%;
}
```

Setting it to

```
.product-info .option.boss_radio {
    width: 39%;
}
```

caused the border to stop overlapping.  
Sometimes alignment can be tricky and fixing one problem will lead to another.  I hope this helps and gets you to where you need to be.

Comment: I tried to use that, because still I couldn't figure out which CSS needed to be tweaked ... Can you maybe look at the URL I've mentioned above ?

Comment: I took a look and added a sample to my answer, see if that gets you somewhere.